# Null Input java

Tags: java, input, null

Hello I am trying to make a program and for it I need to read from the input several times but at some point the input is null. I can't understand what I am doing wrong can you help me?

```
         System.out.print("Give destination folder: \n");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String destination=null;
        String input = null;
        try {
            input = br.readLine();
            //br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        destination=Directory + File.separator +input;
        File destination_folder=new File(destination);
        if (destination_folder.exists()==true){
            System.out.print("");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Folder doesn't exists! Do you want to create it?\n");
            if(Prompt()==true){
                File dir=new File(input);
                dir.mkdir();                        
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Give name of folders to continue\n");
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            input = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String name=input;
        resultList = new ArrayList<File>();
        File Dir=new File(Directory);
        File[] fList = Dir.listFiles();
        resultList.addAll(Arrays.asList(fList)); 
        System.out.print("name=" + name);

        System.out.print("Folders of Directory:\n");
        for (File file : fList) {
             if (file.isDirectory()) {
                 if(file.getName().toLowerCase().contains(name)) 
                    System.out.println(file.getName());
            }
        }



public static boolean Prompt(){
        do{
            System.out.print("Do you want to cotinue? \nPress y or n\n");
            char c = 'a';
            try {
             c = (char) System.in.read();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(c=='y') return true;
            if(c=='n') return false;

        }while(true);
    }
}
```

When I call the function above, if the prompt function is called then the name string is null. So I guess that I have to clear the input in someway for garbage or it is something else wrong?

Comment: *When* does `readLine` return null? If not sure, [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()).

Comment: @user2864740 null if the end of the stream has been reached. How is the stream reached? Is it reached because I press enter after the y or n answer at the prompt function?

Comment: It seems like the null is obtained because of a caught exception. Your exception handling is completely wrong, probably due to some blindly accepting Eclipse's advice on surrounding with try-catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your prompt method to parse BufferedReader br as an argument and use that object to read a character as follows

```
public static boolean Prompt(BufferedReader br){
    do{
        System.out.print("Do you want to cotinue? \nPress y or n\n");
        char c = 'a';
        try {

         c = (char) br.read();//System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(c=='y') return true;
        if(c=='n') return false;

    }while(true);
}
```

reason for getting null for your input is that once you use System.in.read() in your prompt method it won't wait to read the user input when you call BufferedReader.readLine() in the subsequent line.

as Elliott Frisch mentioned it's better to use [java.util.scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 1):

I urge you to use a [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), and to remember to check that there's a line to read with [hasNextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29) before calling [nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) (also, you should always [clean up after yourself](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/clean-up-after-yourself.html)).

```
java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(
    System.in);
try {
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    // use the user's input....
  }
} finally {
  scanner.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a BufferedReader you can do the following.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //Do what you want with the line.
}
```